# Jpackage problem running Server on Win10 what could I be doing wrong?

Tags: java, jpackage

I am a complete newbie when it comes to the finer points of java packaging.

I have written a TCP Data Server using Java-15 via jdk-15 that works quite happily when running under VSCode.

I want to distribute it as MRS_Server.exe hopefully without java needing to be loaded on the host machine nor having to distribute my code.

I have managed to run Jpackage with the following commands:-

jpackage --type app-image --name MRS_Server --input C:\Users\steve\Documents\workspace1_neon\Pi_Server --main-jar C:\Users\steve\Documents\workspace1_neon\Pi_Server\Pi_Server.jar

jpackage --type exe --app-image MRS_Server --name MRS_Server

Which produces MRS_Server-1.0.exe.  Which, in turn, creates the folder C:\Program Files\MRS_Server which includes copies of my code in the MRS_Server\app folder, a MRS_Server\runtime folder which I assume contains all files required to run the server, and files MRS_Server.exe and MRS_Server.ico.

At this point I run C:\Program Files\MRS_Server\MRS_Server.exe ... nothing happens!??  I have run it on a machine without and security programs and added to the windows firewall. It should open a window and await traffic but nothing?  The program is not displayed in the task manager.

What am I missing?  I would rather not have to rewrite the server in another language.

Steve Hall

Answer (score 2):

Turn on `--win-console` to see the actual error messages from your application - more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64609035/executable-created-with-jpackagesilently-fails-if-jar-is-missing/64614660#64614660). Note that `jpackage -add-launcher` for making versions with/without console does not work in JDK15, but is fine if you use JDK14 or JDK16 Early Access so you will have to re-build without `--win-console` later if not needing it permanently.

Also use `--app-version` to ensure that the installation of your second release wipes the first release - more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62675323/cannot-rerun-java-jpackage-installer-if-already-installed-second-time-just-exit/62819060#62819060).

Comment: Tried again with suggested changes this time got:-

Comment: jpackage --type app-image --name MRS_Server --input C:\Users\steve\Documents\workspace1_neon\Pi_Server --main-jar C:\Users\steve\Documents\workspace1_neon\Pi_Server\Pi_Server.jar --win-console --verbose

Using java48.ico (add MRS_Server.ico to the resource-dir to customize).
Warning: Windows Defender may prevent jpackage from functioning. If there is an issue, it can be addressed by either disabling realtime monitoring, or adding an exclusion for the directory "C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.incubator.jpackage8659344422105005200".
Succeeded in building Win Application Image package

Comment: However on running the installer on both machines with/without norton 360 the folder empty folder C:\Program Files\MRS_Server is created.

Comment: The system without Nortonhad Java.lang.Unsupported.ClassVersionError 59.65535 try running with '--enable-preview' This machine has Java 8 installed.

Comment: Just changed JAVA_HOME on this machine and still got error.  Surely the point of jpackage is not to have to load java?

Comment: Uninstalled java still get 59.65535 error.

Comment: Perhaps as you have built your release with `javac --enable-preview` you need jpackage with `--java-options "--enable-preview"` so that the new runtime will handle the preview code

Comment: Also check that your release has it own valid java: `C:\Program Files\MRS_Server\runtime\bin\java -version`. If not use jlink to build a cutdown JRE and use jpackage `--runtime-image`

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned JDK-15 and am using AdoptOpenJDK-16 and am having no problems.  Thanks to all who reponded.

Steve