# exe file generated from jar not running in windows

Tags: java, windows, javafx, jar, jpackage

I have generated an exe file using jpackager in windows, when I install it and try to run, this error is generated.

```
Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
        ... 5 more
```

Any ideas on how to solve this will be really appreciated
This is how I generated the exe file

```
jpackage -t exe --name "wetu" --app-version 1.0 --input "C:\Users\home\Documents\Andrew\Projects\Java\WetuLantern\dist" --dest "C:\Users\home\Documents\Andrew\wetu-exe" --main-jar "WetuLantern.jar" --icon "C:\Users\home\Documents\Andrew\icon.ico" --module-path "C:\Users\home\Downloads\Compressed\javafx-jmods-16" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml,javafx.base  --win-shortcut --win-menu --win-console
```

Comment: start the exe with cmd and show the message.

Comment: It prints nothing on the screen

Answer (score 0):

Activate Windows console with `--win-console` as outlined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64609035/executable-created-with-jpackagesilently-fails-if-jar-is-missing/64614660#64614660). This allow you to identify the error message.

Secondly, the installer does not upgrade the [previous installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62675323/cannot-rerun-java-jpackage-installer-if-already-installed-second-time-just-exit/62819060#62819060) after each build unless you increase the `--app-version` each time or un-install the previous copy before installing new copy.