# Received fatal alert: handshake_failure when running the program as EXE

Tags: java, jsoup, exe

My app uses JSOUP to connect to websites. I am using JSOUP 1.15. In the development environment of Intellij everything as working fine.
Then I generated an EXE file using jpackage.
Her I am getting this error.
The trace is as follows:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:859)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:829)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:366)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:353)
    at com.workingelectrons.susannesrezeptbuch.GetRecipeFromChefkoch.<init>(GetRecipeFromChefkoch.java:32)
    at com.workingelectrons.susannesrezeptbuch.ImportTab.startWebimport(ImportTab.java:192)
    at com.workingelectrons.susannesrezeptbuch.ImportTab.lambda$startImport$3(ImportTab.java:120)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.controls@19/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.controls@19/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.controls@19/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@19/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

As Java I am using openjdk 17.0.2

Thank you

Comment: Have you seen existing questions, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception ?

Comment: Upgraded to Openjdk 18.0.2.1 . Still the same error when running as EXE , but ok in Intellij

Comment: Yes, but I dont use certificates. And in Intellij everything is fine. It must have to do something with the runtime-image. I have seen comments about java - versions, therefore I upgraded to openjdk 18.0.2.1 , but this did not help to solve the problem.

Comment: I upgraded now to the latest java version Oracle 19. But it did not help.

Comment: Using -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose I created debug-output of the handshake.